# Can't seem to wrap my head around recursion in binary search tress

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, binary-search-tree

Salutations community

This is more of a conceptual question, so please bear with me.

I am confused with the following algorithm due to the multiple instances of recursion in the traversion of a binary tree and the order of operations. Im using 
the Preorder algorithm as an example.

Heres the code.

```
1    public static void Preorder(Node node){
2    if (node == null)
3        return;
4    System.out.print(node.element + " ");
5    Preorder(node.left);
6    Preorder(node.right);
7 }
```

What I am confused about is, the chain of command of the recursion call. 
First in the algorithm on the first "iteration", are both Preorder methods that are called on activated simultaneously. Like the methods at line 5 and line 6 simultaneously happen and there is no "waiting " for the other one to get done.

Or is it more like  #6 Prerder() keeps getting called until the base case is hit. 
Then #7 gets called until its base is hit? Also if this is true, how are all the right nodes on left of the sub tree reached, and vice-versa ?

Say you have this, tree (N = any number)

```
    N
   /  \ 
  N    N
 / \    \
 N  N    N
    \
     N
    /  \
   N    N
      /
     N
```

How exactly does the algorithm "reach" these right most nodes on the right sub tree, if the method is constantly repeating a node.left arguments ? Its seems as though you would only get the left most nodes and nothing else.

Im still wraping my head around the whole notion of the nodes.left and nodes.right and how recursion and other algorithms effectively uses them. Seems like a cryptic process, but fascinating to say the least.

Comment: The recursive calls to `Preorder` are also going to iterate the `left` and `right` of each of the subtrees, so all of the nodes will be visited.

Comment: How  ? @4castle , its not like there is a iteration function, or unless (correct me if Im wrong here). the Preorder(node.left ), calls simultanously calls the   Preorder(node.left ) &  Preorder(node.right). Thus its a simultanious recursion call then.

Comment: In this case I'm using the word "iterate" to refer to "iterate over the fields of an object", instead of "iterate over the elements of an array". First it calls `Preorder(node.left);`, then it calls `Preorder(node.right);`. They aren't simultaneous. The second statement won't start until the first statement finishes.

Comment: @castle so since these are not  simultaneous methods, how are the right nodes on the left sub tree being access if the method of the left tree is just, Node.left ? Dont mean to be difficult, Im just perplexed and baffled at how the right side of the left sub tree is being accessed with out there being any commands to instruct it to go to the right most portion of the tree.

Comment: Every recursive call to `Preorder` is going to access the `left` and `right` fields of the parameter you give it, so `Preorder(node.left);` will access `node.left.left` and `node.left.right`, and then each of *those* fields will be recursively accessed (until `null` is encountered).

Comment: @4castle just to make sure i get this.  When a node, refering to Joop Eggen post. When the 2 is iterated over, the compiler will automatically add 4 - 5 - 6 - 7 - 8, just simply by the recursive function "activating it". Thus  when each node.left is activated, it cause a chain reaction for going to the right most nodes on the sub tree, but this is only possible if the base case is hit.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. At each node of the tree, it first prints itself, then it will print all of the left tree, then it will print all of the right tree, then it will return. The "right" chain is activated when the "left" chain fully finishes (that's exactly what the code says).

Answer (score 1):

A picture is worth a thousand words: this happens on numbering each step when preordered:

```
    1
   /  \ 
  2    9
 / \    \
3   4    10
    \
     5
    /  \
   6    7
      /
     8
```